# JUnit 4 PermGen size overflow when running tests in Eclipse and Maven2

Tags: static, junit, mockito, powermock, permgen

I'm doing some unit tests with JUnit, PowerMock and Mockito. I have a lot of test classes annotated with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(SomeClassesNames)` to mock final classes and more than 200 test cases.

Recently I've run into a problem of a PermGen space overflow when I run my entire test suite in Eclipse or Maven2. When I run my test one by one then each of them succeeds.

I did some research about that, however none of the advice helped me (I have increased PermGenSize and MaxPermSize). Recently I've found out that there is one class that contains only static methods and each method returns object mocked with PowerMockito. I'm wondering whether it is a good practice and maybe this is the origin of the problem because static variables are being shared between unit tests?

Generally speaking is it a good practice to have a static class with a lot of static methods which returns static mocked objects?

Comment: Is there a reason why your application has been designed with so many static methods?  Static methods tend to make testing difficult.  Would it be possible for you to have these as non-static methods of some class; then inject an object of that class into whatever code you have that needs it?

Comment: @DavidWallace I would assume from what the OP said that the static methods are used in the tests, they only return mocked objects. They won't be used in the non-test code.

Comment: OK, I read it differently.  @Adam, can you please clarify?  Are the static methods part of your application, or just test scaffolding?

Comment: To clarify static methods are part of test scaffolding.

Comment: Why?  Can't you just make them non-static methods in whatever test class they live in?

Comment: I have changed it however it didn't help much :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Brice says, the problems with PermGen will be coming from your extensive use of mocked objects. Powermock and Mockito both create a new class which sits between the class being mocked and your test code. This class is created at runtime and loaded into PermGen, and is (practically) never recovered. Hence your problems with the PermGen space.

To your question:

1) Sharing of static variables is considered a code smell. It's necessary in some cases, but it introduces depdendencies between tests. Test A needs to run before test B.

2) Usage of static methods to return a mocked object isn't really a code smell, it's a attern which is often used. If you really can't increase your permgen space, you have a number of options:

Use a pool of mocks, with `PowerMock#reset()` when the mock is put back into the pool. This would cut down on the number of creations you're doing.

Secondly, you said that your classes are final. If this is changeable, then you could just use an anonymous class in the test. This again cuts down on the amount of permgen space used:

```
Foo myMockObject = new Foo() {
     public int getBar() { throw new Exception(); }
}
```

Thirdly, you can introduce an interface (use Refactor->Extract Interface in Eclipse), which you then extend with an empty class which does nothing. Then, in your class, you do similar to the above. I use this technique quite a lot, because I find it easier to read:

```
public interface Foo {
  public int getBar();
}

public class MockFoo implements Foo {
  public int getBar() { return 0; }
}
```

then in the class:

```
Foo myMockObject = new MockFoo() {
     public int getBar() { throw new Exception(); }
}
```

I have to admit I'm not a particular fan of mocking, I use it only when necessary, I tend to either extend the class with an anonymous class or create a real MockXXX class. For more information on this point of view, see [Mocking Mocking and Testing Outcomes. by Uncle Bob](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/23/mocking-mocking-and-testing-outcomes)

By the way, in maven surefire, you can always [forkMode=always](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode) which will fork the jvm for each test class. This won't solve your Eclipse problem though.

Comment: I have increased PermGenSize for Surefire reports from default settings to 128MB and the same for JUnit runner in Eclipse - it helped. It's only temporary solution. I think that my test code needs some refactoring anyway, becouse I have about 250 test cases and to run it I need 100MB of permgen memory. In my opinion it's way to much.

Comment: try @PowerMockIgnore(value = {"org.apache.log4j.*"}) http://www.gitshah.com/2010/07/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-when.html

Comment: nicely answered.. and thanks for the post link from Uncle Bob :)

Answer (score 28):

I am getting PermGen errors from Junit in Eclipse too. But I am not using any mocking libs like Mockito nor EasyMock.  However, my code base is large and my Junit tests are using Spring-Test (and are intense and complex test cases).  For this, I need to truly increase the PermGen for all of my Junit tests.

Eclipse applies the Installed JRE settings to the Junit runs - not the eclipse.ini settings.  So to change those:

- Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's
- select the default JRE,  Edit... button
- add to Default VM Arguments: -XX:MaxPermSize=196m

This setting will allow Junit tests to run the more intense TestCases in Eclipse, and avoid the OutOfMemoryError: PermGen.  This should also be low risk because most simple Junit tests will not allocate all of that memory.

Answer (score 5):

First : Mockito is using CGLIB to create mocks, and PowerMock is using Javassist for some other stuff, like removing the final markers, Powermock also loads classes in a new ClassLoader. **CGLIB is known for eating the Permanent Generation** (just google [CGLIB PermGen](https://www.google.com/search?q=CGLIB%20permgen) to find relevant results on the matter).

It's not a straight answer as it depends on details of your project :

1. As you pointed there is static helper class, I don't know if holds static variables with mocks as well, I don't know the details of your code, so this is pure guess, and other readers that actually knows better might correct me.

   It could be the ClassLoader (and at least some of his childrens) that loaded this static class might be kept alive across tests - **it might be because of statics** (which lives in the *Class realm*) or because of some reference somewhere - that means that **if the ClassLoader still lives** (*i.e.* not garbage collected) his loaded classes are not discarded *i.e.* **the classes including the generated ones are still in the PermGen**.
2. These classes might also be huge in size, if you have a lot of these classes to be loaded this might be relevant to have higher PermGen values, especially since Powermock needs to reload classes in a new Classloader for each tests.

Again I don't know the details of your project, so I'm just guessing, but your permanent generation issue might be caused either due to point 1 or point 2, or even both.

Anyway generally speaking I would say yes : having a static class that might return static mocked object does look like a bad practice here, as it usually is in production code. If badly crafted it can leads to ClassLoader's leak (this is nasty!).

In practice I've seen running hundreds of tests (with Mockito only) without ever changing memory parameters and without seeing the CGLIB proxies being unloaded, and I'm not using static stuff appart the ones from the Mockito API.

If you are using a Sun/Oracle JVM you can try these options to track what's happening :

`-XX:+TraceClassLoading` and `-XX:+TraceClassUnloading` or `-verbose:class`

Hope that helps.

---

*Outside the scope of this question :*

Personnaly I don't like using to use Powermock anyway, I only use it in corner cases *e.g.* for testing unmodifiable legacy code. Powermock is too intrusive imho, it has to spawn for each test a new classloader to perform its deeds (modifying the bytecode), you have to heavily annotate the test classes to be able to mock, ...
In my opinion for usual development all these little inconvenience outweight the benefit of the hability to mock finals. Even Johan the author of Powermock, once told me he was recommanding Mockito instead and keeping Powermock for some specific purpose.

Don't get me wrong here: Powermock is a fantastic piece of technology, that really help when you have to deal with (poorly) designed legacy code that you cannot change. But not for the every day developpement, especially if praticing TDD.

Comment: What do you mean by huge size? Huge test classes or huge classes that are being tested? I have more then 250 test cases and it uses 100MB from permgen. Do you think that it's to much? I'm also using Powermock only in corner cases. Thanks for your answer - tracking options helped me.

Comment: @Adam yes it's gigantic, I have a pure unit test suite of ~250 test classes with ~1220 test methods that extensively uses Mockito, and the permanent generation size tops around 12MB. I only saw hundred(s) MB of PerMGen in running applications. It might take some time, but you really should try to identify what is causing to eat up the PermGen. Maybe the tests are not really unit tests, and are using Spring contexts, etc., this could be a legitimate explanation.

Comment: The problem is that when I write test cases for one class that uses mockito or powermock (for example some manager class) then the class that is mocked is also loaded. What causes the problem is that every time this class is mocked it is loaded. I have discovered it when I have run my tests with parameters that you have recommended and  -XX:+PrintGCDetails. I initialise mocks in method annotated with Bore and in method annotated with After I assign to each of them null. I don't know why those classes are not garbage collected. I will try to call garbage collection directly.

Comment: Garbage collection Runtime.getRuntime().gc() didn't help :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, that's an issue this CGLIB, if those classes are not garbage collected, it's certainly because the classloader is still referenced somewhere, maybe via some other class referenced in a static field, or something. Anyway if that's indeed a classloader leak, it's the nasty one, and it will be difficult to locate and solve. Also you might want to track classes that are loaded multiple times. And it could be interesting to measure memory for each test class. Additionnaly you might need to actually analyze the memory with tools such as jmap / Eclipse MAT / Netbeans profiler.

Comment: PowerMock is admirable technology, but it's true that its heavy use of custom classloading can cause problems sometimes. Fortunately, custom classloading (which, BTW, is what CGLIB also does) is not necessary to enable "unlimited" mocking. JMockit does it by modifying the bytecode of already loaded classes without creating new ones. (Also, it doesn't require annotating the test classes.)

Comment: @Rogerio That is impossible in Java without the help of an agent. Do JMockit uses one ?

Comment: @Brice Yes, it uses `java.lang.instrument`, which requires the loading of a Java agent into the running JVM. However, this is transparent to users, ie, they don't need to add a `-javaagent` parameter. (Other agent-based tools do require it, but that is only because they didn't take advantage of the Attach API.)

Comment: @Rogerio OK, but the attach API is only available in Java 6 if I remember correctly (I remember slides of JBoss Byteman). I still know many project still relying on a JDK 5. Anyway it's really good to know for future works, now that we have created an extension point to create mocks using a different engine.

Comment: @Brice Yes, use of the Attach API requires JDK 1.6+. Not a real problem, though, as most users already run their tests on Java 6+, and those stuck with JDK 1.5 can always use the `-javaagent` parameter. (In fact, what happens is that some projects still *deploy* to a Java 5 server, but that doesn't prevent them from safely running tests in development/build machines with JDK 1.6 or even newer - just use "javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5".)

Comment: @Rogerio Agreed, still I wouldn't want to impose that, either the agent parameter or running the tests in JDK6 :)